# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException while deploying on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I was working on an WEB Application in my Netbeans IDE and i deployed this successfully in the Glassfish server that comes with the Netbeans installation. But when i tried running the same web application on the TOMCATinstance that came with the same Netbeans Installation. i get a NameNotFound Exception. Not sure how to resolve this.

**javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [com.test.TestServlet/service] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [com.test.TestServlet].
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:818)
    org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:166)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)**

Not sure how to get past this...any solutions to this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you display the contents of your context.xml, web.xml, perhaps even server.xml?

Comment: Context.xml looks like:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>

Comment: Cannot add server.xml and web.xml files here as it exceeds the limit. any pointers that you might be hinting at?

Comment: "javax.naming.NameNotFoundException" leads me to JNDI-related possibilities, hence the 3 XML files; you only have to show the parts that's related to JNDI (such as <Resource/>, <ResourceLink/> and/or <resource-ref/>; you may refer to Tomcat's official documentation for more information) and show them by "edit"ing your question instead of posting in comment(s)!